# Upload HTML5 canvas as a blob

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas, which I can paint to the DOM without a problem as well as save for the user locally using:

```
storCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) { saveAs(blob, name + ".png");});
```

(note: I've included canvas-toBlob.js for cross platform support, from http://eligrey.com/blog/post/saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

Now, what I would like to do is send the same canvas element to the server. I thought I could do something like:

```
storCanvas.toBlob(function(blob) {upload(blob);});
```

where upload(blob); is:

```
function upload(blobOrFile)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'upload_file.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) { /*uploaded*/ };

    // Listen to the upload progress.
    var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable)
        {
          progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
          progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(blobOrFile);

}
```

(cribbed from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)

Now, I thought I this would work, but my PHP page (which I can do a POST to successfully using a standard HTML form) reports back (via firebug) that it got an invalid file of 0kB. I assume that the issue is in my conversion to a blob, but I'm not sure the correct way to go about it...

Answer (score 12):

I came across the same problem when learning about blobs myself. I believe the problem is in submitting the `blob` itself through the `XMLHttpRequest` rather than putting it inside a `FormData` like this:

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var formData = new FormData(); //this will submit as a "multipart/form-data" request
  formData.append("image_name", blob); //"image_name" is what the server will call the blob
  upload(formData); //upload the "formData", not the "blob"
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Massive cheers for this answer!!  Note: Yes, "image_name" is the form's key for the image, but to send a desired filename with the file, it's: formData.append("image_name", blob, "myFileName.jpg"); (src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append )

Answer (score -1):

You can use this module for upload blob.

blobtools.js (https://github.com/extremeFE/blobtools.js)

```
//include blobtools.js
blobtools.uploadBlob({ // upload blob
  blob: blob,
  url: uploadUrl, // upload url
  fileName : 'paste_image.png' // upload file name
  callback: callback // callback after upload
});
```

Comment: This single module doesn't seem to offer much improvement compared to the native method: formData.append("image_name", blob, "myFileName.jpg");

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if want this. But how about converting the canvas element into image data url and then sending it to the server and then writing it on the server.
Something like

```
function canvas2DataUrl(canvasElementId){
  var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvasElementId");
  var imgData = canvasElement.toDataURL("image/png");
  return imgData;
}
```

Comment: do not go this route. i started down this route and it turned out to be more complex than initially thought. after you decode the base64 to a bin you still are missing headers. might as well go to the file or blob upload route